# Performing A Complex Join With Datetimes

Tags: apache-pig

I have two data sets; one contains a username, an assigned ID, and a period of time when the ID is valid,

```
data1: {username: chararray, id: chararray, start_time: datetime, stop_time: datetime}
```

and the other contains timestamped events generated by the user identified by the ID.

```
data2: {user_id: chararray, event_data: chararray, event_time: datetime)
```

I'm trying to join the two sets so that I can match the username to the event during the time period the ID is valid. Essentially, I want to apply the following criteria to the join, in SQL lingo:

```
WHERE (data1.id = data2.user_id) AND (data2.event_time > data1.start_time) AND (data2.event_time < data1.stop_time)
```

I tried the following script:

```
joined = JOIN data1 BY id, data2 BY user_id;
matched = FILTER joined BY (SecondsBetween(start_time, event_time) < (long) 0) AND (SecondsBetween(event_time, stop_time) < (long) 0);
```

The problem is that I get an "ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output" error when I try to run it. I'm not sure what the error means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

How are you loading the data? I ran you code with super simple, one line test data and it did not give me any problems. Below is my code and test data.

**Pig script**

```
tmp_data1 = LOAD 'data1.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (username:chararray, id:chararray, start_time:chararray, stop_time:chararray);
tmp_data2 = LOAD 'data2.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (user_id:chararray, event_data:chararray, event_time:chararray);
data1 = FOREACH tmp_data1 GENERATE
    username, id, ToDate(start_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS start_time, ToDate(stop_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS stop_time; 
data2 = FOREACH tmp_data2 GENERATE
    user_id, event_data, ToDate(event_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS event_time; 
joined = JOIN data1 BY id, data2 BY user_id;
matched = FILTER joined BY (SecondsBetween(start_time, event_time) < (long) 0) AND (SecondsBetween(event_time, stop_time) < (long) 0);
dump matched;
```

**data1.txt** (should be tab delimited)

```
abc abc 2015-01-01 00:00:00 2015-01-02 00:00:00
```

**data2.txt** (should be tab delimited)

```
abc abc 2015-01-01 01:00:00
```

Comment: I may have found my problem. The example above is a necessary simplification of the actual data I'm working with. In the actual script, I added the relation prefixes (i.e., 'data1::start_time', 'data2::event_time') to the matched relation definition and that took care of the error that was being generated.